# Can I expose a .less/.scss reference file globally in Webpack?

Tags: sass, less, webpack

We have a project using Webpack with css modules. To apply scoped namespaces, each component has its own .less file. Inside that .less file, we import our common.less file for references so we can use it like so:

```
@import (reference) "../global.less";
.navbar { 
    .navbar;
}
```

This seems pretty convoluted but results in an encapsulated class pairing with its component and allows the others to develop the global.less file internally without having to work with React.

My issue with this, beyond the redundant class wrapping, is each component that imports this rather large global.less file appears to be adding nearly a second to our webpack build.

I'm curious if there is a mechanism that will allow me to expose the contents of global.less for referencing within these files? I've found Webpack can shim js modules. I'm essentially looking for a .less or .scss equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `commonChunkPlugin`, then add your `global.less` path to it, in that way it will be compiled only once in another js file.

[here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#1-commons-chunk-for-entries)

Comment: Ideally, global.less wouldn't be exposed on the page at all. We would only use it for referencing in the modularized (namespaced, encapsulated, etc) component-level css.